# What is this ribbon cable connector?

Tags: connector, identification, ribbon-cable

[image: Image of ribbon cable connector]

I plan to make a circuit for a system and most of parts in the system use this type of connector. What is it called? (in the picture it is 10 pins while there are also 14 pins in the system)

Comment: The cable connector does not seem to match the PCB's connector. Is that correct?

Comment: Hans, what's the pitch (distance between wires) of the ribbon cable?  @gbulmer  I think, the side of the connector which mates with the PCB header is shown on the bottom-right picture.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - Thanks. I hadn't 'parsed' it that way, but now I can.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The pitch of the ribbon cable is 0.05 inch (1.27 mm). It is a general one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the connector is part of the Molex PicoFlex surface mount series. All connector headers, housings, and mates can be found [here](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoflex&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors).

The only thing I see in the pictures is the blade pins aren't staggered, but that just might be laziness by molex. I looked through all "blade pin" style connectors on digikey and this is the only match I could see.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think this is right one to order.